# Authenticate to website in Javascript to access back-end

Tags: angularjs, cookies, lotus-domino, saprfc, ltpa

I am currently developing an application for my company that is essentially a phone book application. Let's say that you are a manager - named Alex - and have 3 developers reporting to you: Mike, Matt and Mark. In order to gather the contact information about these 3 developers who are reporting to you so that it can be displayed in the front-end, you must make a call to a back-end Lotus Notes Java Agent, that calls an SAP ABAP function module.

I am able to access this Agent in the browser, by authenticating to our Company's home-website, which generates an LTPAToken cookie and a MySAPSSO2 cookie. Once you are able to authenticate to this website, you can call this backend agent and get the expected data to return.

My issue is that I am not sure how to do this authentication in the front-end application. How can I acquire the LTPAToken and the MySAPSSO2 cookies in order to be able to call this back-end agent to acquire the data?

I can provide any further information needed, thanks guys.
-Mike

Comment: You will get the ltpa token once you are authenticated towards the Company home web-site, so in your application you would probably need to make an authentication request towards that site to get the token. Since I don't know how you intend to implement your application it is hard to tell how to do that request.